# Client Credential Flow?

Tags: identityserver4

Just want to verify my findings before we proceed forward.  I have an internal API that is not exposed to our customers.  It will be hidden behind the UI layer.  The Client(s) of the service is not a user, but most likely a service account.  I believe I need to use Client Credential Flow in this case?  Can you confirm?

Comment: yes, you can use client credential flow  .

Answer (score 0):

Yes for any background service or Demon application you have got to use client credential flow. This will require you to pass the application id, client secret, resource end points etc to get the authorization token. It is very important to note that the azure application id must have the required permissions for the specific api you are using.